# Adobe AIR Socket Web Server PHP Support

Tags: php, actionscript-3, air

I have been developing a web server in AIR/AS3 in Flash CS6.
I am wondering if it would be possible to have PHP support?
Like, loading PHP pages on the web server.

Comment: Do you have any clue what  socket connection is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags are not keywords.  That is, the tags `web` and `server` are independent, and that combining them will not be useful to discuss web servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways AIR/AS3 could utilize PHP as backend.  The most common usage would be using PHP as data pump where PHP send data, and Flash would render the data by assigning the data to text fields, controls, or translating data into drawing commands that output things like charts or graphics.

To use PHP as data pump, the best would be using PHP to send and receive AMF with software such as [amfPHP](http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/).  Others might use PHP for REST, Web Service or even XML Socket.

Given you mention about Adobe AIR, which comes with capability of rendering html better than Flash.  You can create html controls that load PHP web pages.  Such approach would be limited in many ways because there is little interaction AS3 could perform against the PHP webpage, and such approach would be further limited should you want to deploy your AIR applications on mobile platform.

Your question is rather broad, so I hope my answers could get you to have more specific ideas.